# Фильтрация списка по модулю числа

Tags: python, список

```
list = [25,16,43,2,66]
list.sort(key=lambda x: x % 5)
```

Как отсортировать список и оставить в нём только числа, которые по модулю больше 5?
Предположение было на функцию `abs()`

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что такое "по модулю больше 5", может меньше? Или "по модулю 8, значения больше 5"?

Comment: @Komdosh Берёте модуль числа, проверяете, что он больше 5

Comment: Есть массив, надо отфильтровать его чтобы в не. Остались числа которые по модулю больше 5

Comment: @nomnoms12 аа, модуль в смысле знак, подумал по модулю с основанием 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Метод [`sort`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) не удаляет элементы из массива. Если хотите фильтровать, то используйте функцию [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter).

***Пример:***

```py
li = [25, 16, 43, 2, 66]
li = list(filter(lambda x: abs(x) > 5, li))

print(li)
```

***stdout:***

```py
[25, 16, 43, 66]
```

Comment: Да я автору вопроса в предыдущем его вопросе все подсказки дал, а он только слово "фильтрация" воспринял, а задание сам делать так и не захотел :/

Comment: @CrazyElf ...(((